# Attempt to de-reference a null object on when calling Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjName).getDescribe();

Tags: visualforce, permissions, field-level-security

I receive an error on a web page : Attempt to de-reference a null object

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sObjResult = GLOBAL_DESCRIBE.get(sObjName).getDescribe();
```

First i thought that my user doesn't have the rigth CRUD access to the object "Job_Match__c" but my user is the administrator of the org.

Here is the call stack I receive and after the code that cause the error. I had the debug log after.

Visualforce Error

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Error is in expression '{!initialize}'
>   in component  
>   in page xyz:startjobmatch: **Class.xxx.FLSCheck.hasPermissionObject**: 
>   line 14, column 1 **Class.xyz.SecurityHelper.validatePermissions**: 
>   line 121, column 1 
>   Class.xyz.SecurityHelper.allowOrDie: line 101, column 1
>   Class.xyz.StartJobMatchController.initialize: line 67, column 1
>   Class.xyz.FLSCheck.hasPermissionObject: line 14, column 1
>   Class.xyz.SecurityHelper.validatePermissions: line 121, column 1
>   Class.xyz.SecurityHelper.allowOrDie: line 101, column 1
>   Class.xyz.StartJobMatchController.initialize: line 67, column 1

code for Class.xyz.SecurityHelper.validatePermissions :

```
private static void validatePermissions(String sObjName,
                           List<String> fieldNames, String operationType)
  {
        if (!FLSCheck.hasPermissionObject(sObjName, operationType))
        {
            throwException(FLSCheck.GLOBAL_DESCRIBE.get(sObjName).getDescribe(), 
                                                     null, operationType);
        }

        if (fieldNames != null)
        {
            validateFieldsPermissions(sObjName, fieldNames, operationType);
        }
  }
```

code for Class.xxx.FLSCheck.hasPermissionObject

```
public with sharing class FLSCheck 
{
  public static final Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GLOBAL_DESCRIBE = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

    public static final String READ_ACCESS = 'Read';
    public static final String CREATE_ACCESS = 'Create';
    public static final String EDIT_ACCESS = 'Edit';
    public static final String DELETE_ACCESS = 'Delete';
    public static final String UPSERT_ACCESS = 'Upsert';

    public static Boolean hasPermissionObject(String sObjName, String operationType)
    {
      System.debug('sObjName '+sObjName);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sObjResult = GLOBAL_DESCRIBE.get(sObjName).getDescribe();
        Boolean hasPermission = hasPermission(sObjResult, null, operationType);
        return hasPermission;
    }
```

Debug log :

> 21:58:39.0
>   (266265385)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[3]|Schema.getGlobalDescribe()
>   21:58:39.0
>   (266421749)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[3]|FLSCheck.GLOBAL_DESCRIBE|"{acceptedeventrelation=AcceptedEventRelation,
>   account=Account, }"|0x874a1ce
>   [1]|01p610000024TMO|SecurityHelper.SecurityHelper()
>   [67]|01p610000024TMO|jobou363gmail.SecurityHelper.allowOrDie(String,
>   String) 21:58:39.0
>   (268531485)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[99]|sObjName|"Job_Match__c"
>   [99]|operationType|String|false|false 21:58:39.0
>   (268538785)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[99]|operationType|"Create" 21:58:39.0
>   (268548126)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[101]|Bytes:5
>   [101]|01p610000024TMO|jobou363gmail.SecurityHelper.validatePermissions(String,
>   List, String) 21:58:39.0
>   (268697345)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[118]|sObjName|"Job_Match__c"
>   [118]|fieldNames|List|true|false 21:58:39.0
>   (268710089)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[118]|fieldNames|null|[118]|operationType|String|false|false
>   21:58:39.0
>   (268717042)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[118]|operationType|"Create"[121]|Bytes:5[121]|01p610000024TLs|jobou363gmail.FLSCheck.hasPermissionObject(String,
>   String) 21:58:39.0
>   (268778703)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[11]|sObjName|"Job_Match__c"
>   21:58:39.0 (268784964)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[11]|operationType|"Create"
>   21:58:39.0 (268888129)|USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|sObjName Job_Match__c
>   [14]|Map.get(Object)
>   [121]|01p610000024TLs|jobou363gmail.FLSCheck.hasPermissionObject(String,
>   String)
>   [101]|01p610000024TMO|jobou363gmail.SecurityHelper.validatePermissions(String,
>   List, String)
>   [67]|01p610000024TMO|jobou363gmail.SecurityHelper.allowOrDie(String,
>   String) 21:58:39.0 (269078313)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false 21:58:39.0
>   (269166521)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   de-reference a null object
>
> Class.xyz.FLSCheck.hasPermissionObject: line 14, column 1
>   Class.xyz.SecurityHelper.validatePermissions: line 121, column 1
>   Class.xyz.SecurityHelper.allowOrDie: line 101, column 1
>   Class.xyz.StartJobMatchController.initialize: line 67, column 1
>   21:58:39.0 (269183992)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|StartJobMatchController
>   invoke(initialize)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message just describes the situation where the object name you passed in wasn't found in the describe map and your code assumes it is always going to be found and is trying to call `getDescribe()` on `null`.

Writing it like this should resolve at least the exception. You should handle the scenario appropriately for your situation.

```
public static Boolean hasPermissionObject(String sObjName, String operationType) {
    System.debug('sObjName '+sObjName);

    // Get the item from the map
    Schema.SObjectType objType = GLOBAL_DESCRIBE.get(sObjName);

    // make sure we got an object token
    if (objType == null) {
        // bad object name?
        system.debug('The thing couldn\'t be found. Cannot call getDescribe');
        return null;

    } else {

        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sObjResult = objType.getDescribe();
        Boolean hasPermission = hasPermission(sObjResult, null, operationType);
        return hasPermission;
    }

}
```

Comment: I recently found an example of how this can happen: if the version of the class doesn't support that object, it won't appear in the schema. For forwards compatibility, you should always check for null first.